# Is there a way set SliceStart back a few days?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on a Data Factory where I want to query data from few days back.

I am executing a stored procedure that takes input based on the slice start:

**For Example:**

```
"value": "$$Text.Format('{0:dd}', SliceStart)"
```

So a run that starts on Friday queries data from Monday.

I can do some date manipulation in the stored procedure, but ideally I would like the window start and end date reflect the data the was copied.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V1 you can specify "delay" in your [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-create-pipelines#policies) of your activities. This allows you to postpone the execution of your activity. The example shows a couple of minutes, but I think you can use that to make it execute a few days later, while show the date/time of your slice.

Comment: I was just looking at the delay and wondered if that would work. Will try it out and if it does I will mark this an my answer.

Comment: The delay doesn't appear to be working beyond hours. The documentation example shows "00:10:00" for ten minutes. I am unable so far to find a documentation reference that will verify that "02:00:00:00" would translate  to 2 days. It doesn't error, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: Did you try 48:00:00?

Comment: I ended up formatting the delay as `"delay": "5.00:00:00"` and that worked just as I was hoping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Date.AddDays` function in order to acomplish this. From your screenshot and the fact you are talking about slices, I assume you are using DataFactory version 1. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-functions-variables#data-factory-functions) is overview of ADF v1 functions.

For your example, to get date that is 4 days before `SliceStart`, you would write something like

`"value": "$$Text.Format('{0:dd}', Date.AddDays(SliceStart, -4))"`

Comment: I am using version one. Ideally I would like the slice dates illustrated in the screenshot to reflect the dates of copied the data. As apposed to mentally subtracting 4 days.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your meaning there now... Could you please clarify a bit, how often is the data copied and how often is your stored procedure executed. And how one relates to another.

Comment: I am going to mark your response as the answer. It doesn't get what I want in terms display in the monitoring windows, but it does copy the data when I want it copied.